# PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT и несколько баз данных

Tags: mysql, pdo

В документации PHP про `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` говорится:

> Постоянные соединения не закрываются при завершении работы скрипта,
>   они кэшируются и используются повторно, когда другой скрипт
>   запрашивает соединение с теми же учетными данными.

Что называется "учетными данными"?

Если есть подключение к базе данных:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
```

Подключение без указания базы данных и кодировки будет создавать новый коннект или использовать уже открытый?

```
$dbh2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае это неважно. Код вида

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
$dbh2 = new PDO(...);
```

**всегда** будет открывать два соединения. Безотносительно к тому, какой тип соединения используется и какие параметры передаются.

Также хочу отметить, что если речь о доступе к разным базам данных, которые доступны одному и тому же пользователю, то больше одного соединения в данном случае не нужно: всегда можно выбрать БД либо стандартным запросом `USE db_name` либо указать прямо в запросе через точку перед именем таблицы.